# UITabBar small gap on the end when there are 3 tabs

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm customising the UITabBar in my app. I have 3 tabs so when one is selected it has a background that spans 1/3 of the width of the screen. The only problem is, the screen is 320pt, so divide by 3 and we have a non-integer, thus leaving this horrible gap on the end. I set the background images of the selected state to 106pts and then tried it at 107pts, but that didn't help at all. Here is a picture of the TabBar demonstrating the nasty gap at the end.

[image]

It's quite hard to see, but it is there. Does anyone have advice as to how I can get rid of it. This is a subclassed UITabBar so obviously I can make modifications, but I would prefer to keep the fix as simple as possible.

Regards,
Mike

Comment: set it 107,106 and 107...

Comment: @Rajneesh071 As mentioned on another answer, you can't set the width of a UITabBarItem. You could only do so if you create your own custom TabBar from scratch.

Comment: m telling about custom tabBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I've got a little fix, but it's not particularly elegant. I increased the UITabBar width to 321pts so an extra point is being drawn off screen, causing a tab (not sure which one) to expand in size, thus filling the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Give the central element the width of `deviceWidth / numberOfTabs + deviceWidth % numberOfTabs`, and the others `deviceWidth / numberOfTabs`. This way the central element will be 108px and the others 106pxs.

Comment: I don't think you can manually set the width of a UITabBarItem.

Comment: In that case, you might be better of using a ready-made tab bar component that offers more customisation. I recommend AKTabBarController: https://github.com/alikaragoz/AKTabBarController